# Change value of first input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some spinner with font-awesome to style input type number with bootstrap but i have problem with event value, if I have more input type number on page it change value for all of them, but i need only for that one that is edited

Here is where i have problem

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And here you can look full example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGqLbv

Comment: use `$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val` instead of `$('.spinner input').val`

Comment: Please provide full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `this` keyword in the click event handlers to reference the button which was clicked. From that element you can traverse the DOM to find the related input. Try this:

```js
$('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.spinner').find('input').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) + 1;
  });
});
$('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.spinner').find('input').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) - 1;
  });
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 100%;
}
.spinner input {
  text-align: left;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical > .btn:last-child {
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group-btn-vertical i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 input-spinner</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="42">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use closest() method for find closest spinner then find input

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $closest_input= $(this).closest('.spinner').find('input');
    $closest_input.val( parseInt($closest_input.val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $closest_input= $(this).closest('.spinner').find('input');
    $closest_input.val( parseInt($closest_input.val(), 10) - 1);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplyfied:

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn').on('click', function() {
    var down = $(this).is(':last-of-type');
    $(this).parents('.spinner').find('input').val(function(i, v) {
       return parseInt(v, 10) + 1 * (down ? -1 : 1);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```